# applyForce Speed going faster

Tags: lua, coronasdk, physics

Hey I have this problem where If I tap and hold the screen, the player gains speed going up on Y.

What I would prefer is that the player taps the screen (and holds to float up) and he goes up at steady speed (without getting quicker).

Here is the function for float speed and touch event:

```
function activateJets(ship,event)
    ship:applyForce(0, -1.0, ship.x, ship.y)
    print("run")
end

function touchScreen(event)
    print("touch")
    if event.phase == "began" then
        ship.enterFrame = activateJets
        Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", ship)
    end
    if event.phase == "ended" then
        Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", ship)
   end    
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch", touchScreen)
```

Sorry if this doesn't make sense. Here is a general idea of what I want:

- player touches screen (and holds)
- object then floats up at consistent speed (no speed gain)
- player releases touch
- object drops normally

Answer (score 0):

The physics involved prevents you from doing that: you are applying a constant force to your ship. According to Newton's laws (simulated by the physics library), this means a constant acceleration, thus a linear increase in speed.

The behavior you want (which is not coherent with real physics) is an instant acceleration to your target speed and then no speed variation. Thus it should be enough to set the speed of your ship to a constant value using [`shipSetLinearVelocity()`](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/Body/setLinearVelocity.html) inside your `activateJets` function. Of course you should reset the speed to zero when the touch has ended.

Comment: Thanks for that Lorenzo, it works alot better with LinearVelocity. However is there a way to smooth the velocity so that when I remove touch and re- touch (began) it doesnt just stop and then float up? I need it to go smoothly in 1 motion.